# NPM packages version conflict

Tags: node.js, npm, ionic2, rxjs

packages version mess:

[image: packages version mess]

I'm a newbie on NPM and have been struggling to create an ionic 2 application. I can't figure out how to solve all these packages version conflict. Before of the commands showed in the picture I've performed: a clean of the node_modules, npm cache clean, npm unpdate -g npm and npm install.

Here is my package.json:

```
 {
  "name": "io.cordova.myappb7116d",
  "author": "",
  "homepage": "",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/forms": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.2.1",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^3.1.0",
    "@ionic-native/http": "^3.4.4",
    "@ionic-native/native-storage": "^3.4.4",
    "ionic-angular": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "ionic-native": "2.2.11",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "localforage-cordovasqlitedriver": "^1.6.0",
    "npm-install-version": "^6.0.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
    "sw-toolbox": "^3.6.0",
    "uuid": "^3.0.1",
    "zone.js": "0.6.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "^1.1.4",
    "typescript": "2.0.9"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [],
  "-vs-binding": {
    "BeforeBuild": [
      "ionic:build"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: please add your package.json to the question...

Comment: you still on RC4 i recommend you to update the package json as ionic says on the changelog and then try to install all

Answer (score 0):

I followed [Fernando's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43493884/npm-packages-version-conflict#comment74049582_43493884):

> you still on RC4 i recommend you to update the package json as ionic says on the changelog and then try to install all

However I actually I haven't edited manually the package.json so far, I thought npm would have managed the version conflicts installing the latest possible packages version.

Eventually I edited the packages.json in order to switch to the latest ionic version [here](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#steps-to-upgrade).

Afterwards I performed an `npm install` and the error has disappeared.